# Simple audio equalizer for Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm looking for an Equalizer app for Android that:

- is very simple and basic but works well
- does not require many permissions
- does not send data to third party (and even, does not use mobile data or Wifi all, that's not needed)
- does not display ads

A simple Equalizer with a few bands that allows the user to increase/decrease the bass when listening to music with Bluetooth speakers.

I searched the Play Store, but I couldn't find an app that has points 1. 2. 3. 4.

Answer (score 1):

Have used this one for years works well.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weebly.kainz.simple_equalizer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66108)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).